# OptimisticLockException test behaviour with unit test

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, locking, optimistic-locking

I want to test the behavior of an OptimisticLockException.

My entity:

```
@Entity(name = "")
@Table(name = "")
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EntityA
{

   @Id
   private String id;
   @Version
   private Timestamp lastChange;
```

My update Method:

```
public void update(EntityA entityA, String attribute)
try {
            entityA.setSomeAttribute(attribute);
            jpaRepository.save(entityA);
            return;
         } catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
            log.debug(e.getMessage());
         }
```

My Unittest:

```
EntityA entity_1 = createEntity("789", 2);
EntityA entity_2 = createEntity("987", 2);
service.update(entity_1);
assertThrows(OptimisticLockException.class, () -> service.update(entity_2)); // this one should throw an OptimisticLockException 
verify(jpaRepository).save(entity_1);
```

The second call of `update` doesn't throw an `OptimisticLockException`

Comment: Are your update calls done in separate transactions or the same one? Save is likely a no-op - nothing happens until the transaction is synchronized and the context flushes statements to the database, so your try/catch around the save call isn't likely to ever get an OptimisticLockException unless you force a flush on the context somehow, or ensure the save is in its own transaction.

Comment: two differents transactions?

Comment: There is no optimistic lock exception because there is nothing changed between the save calls.

Comment: if you catch it in the catch block, the test won't pick it up.

Comment: @dan1st even i don't catch the exception, it isn't throw.

Comment: You do have a `try`-`catch`-block in `update()` - even if it threw the exception. `assertThrows()` would fail.

Comment: i removed the `try`-`catch` but the `exception` is not threw